# adding footerview to the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Friends. Problem in adding footerview to the listview. I have used the following code to add footerview.

```
TextView totalIncome = new TextView(this);
TextView totalExpense = new TextView(this);
totalIncome.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
totalExpense.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
totalIncome.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
totalExpense.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
totalIncome.setText("Total Income is : " + tIncome + "");
totalExpense.setText("Total Expense is : " + tExpense + "");
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
lv1.addFooterView(totalIncome);
lv1.addFooterView(totalExpense);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But My problem is while changing the list content dynamically the footerview goes down for some steps. I don't why it is moving. Please help me friends.

For ref:

[image]

After changing the content

[image]

see the gap in between list to footerview friends. I didn't want this space. I tried to removefooterview while changing content. But I can't. I have searched lot through internet. But I didn't find any solution friends. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you add another data is the footer view will be moved down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. To Remove Footer View**

There is a method of `ListView` to remove `FooterView`,

```
lv.removeFooterView(v);
```

You only need to take care that you are *passing the same view which you have added*, that means save `totalIncome` and `totalExpense` textview objects, make them `static` and at time to remove pass the same.

**2. To Remove the Space**

Not Sure, still working on it.

I guess, that's happening as once your have set header/footer to listview and then set adapter to listview, header/footer views get placed at their place and while modifying your list content those views will not get changed, *Suggestion* : Try removing and adding views again when you call `notifyDatasetChanged` method for adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try to remove and readd the footer view when you change the content of the listview

to remove :

```
lv1.removeFooterView(totalIncome);
lv1.removeFooterView(totalExpense);
```

to readd

```
lv1.addFooterView(totalIncome);
lv1.addFooterView(totalExpense);
```